# Trouble Inporting data from a csv file, loop through the tickers, scrape data from finviz.com, and export to a csv file for more analysis

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, web-scraping

I'm having trouble putting everything together. I would like to (1) pull a list of stock tickers from a csv file. (2) loop through all the stock tickers into finviz.com to use to pull certain key data points. (3) Extract all the data into another csv file for more analysis. Here is my code I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt

Symbol = []

with open('shortlist.csv') as csvDataFile:
csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
for row in csvReader:
    Symbol.append(row[0])


def get_fundamental_data(df):
for symbol in df.index:
    try:
        url = 'http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' + symbol.lower()
        soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, features='html5lib')
        for m in df.columns:
            df.loc[symbol, m] = fundamental_metric(soup, m)
    except Exception, e:
        print (symbol, 'not found')
return df


def fundamental_metric(soup, metric):
return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text


metric = [  # 'Inst Own',
        # 'Insider Own',
'Price',
'Shs Outstand',
'Shs Float',
'Short Float',
'Short Ratio',
'Book/sh',
'Cash/sh',
'Rel Volume',
'Earnings',
'Avg Volume',
'Volume',
]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=symbol, columns=metric)
df = get_fundamental_data(df)

print df

df.to_csv('finviz_' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv')
```

Attached is my shortlist.csv to import:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdhMh.png)

The error I get is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aldZ.png)

I'm using Python 3 on Pycharm.

The results should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2moe.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Best practice is to include all the relevant text in your question. Images of text are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

your "symbol" define in the function `get_fundamental_data()`
You can't use the "symbol" out of the for loop or function

Answer (score 0):

One of these three methods should get you pretty close to where you want to be.

Method 1:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
url_list = [url_base + s for s in tckr]

with open('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Downloads\\SO.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            fpage = requests.get(url)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage.content, 'html.parser')

            # write header row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

            # write body row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))            
        except HTTPError:
            print("{} - not found".format(url))
```

Method 2:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&s=ta_topgainers&o=price&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,25,63,64,65,66,67'
html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
main_div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'screener-content'})

light_rows = main_div.find_all('tr', class_="table-light-row-cp")
dark_rows = main_div.find_all('tr', class_="table-dark-row-cp")

data = []
for rows_set in (light_rows, dark_rows):
    for row in rows_set:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            val = cell.a.get_text()
            row_data.append(val)
        data.append(row_data)

#   sort rows to maintain original order
data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(data).to_csv("AAA.csv", header=False)
```

Method 3:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
url_list = [url_base + s for s in tckr]

with open('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/today.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            fpage = requests.get(url)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage.content, 'html.parser')

            # write header row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

            # write body row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))            
        except HTTPError:
            print("{} - not found".format(url))
```